# Why is my nic ethN suddenly called p18pN?

Tags: network-interface

After a reboot my network interface `eth1` is now called `p18p1` messing up my network setup. What causes this change of name?

I'm using Linux 4.0.5 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newer kernel versions use a new numbering.  This was changed to get a better consistency in network device numbering when adding new network cards. All new kernel versions use this new numbering, like `enp4s6` instead of `eth0`.  As Aaron pointed out, these are locations on the bus (PCI etc.), so unless the devices are plugged elsewhere they always get the same name, irrespective of other devices or scan order. Please see here for more rationale: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/ .

These interfaces can also be renamed, please see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/217635/how-to-rename-an-ethernet-interface .

The change was analogue to using disk/partition UUIDs instead of `/dev/sda1` etc. - to keep everything working when adding new hardware.

Comment: One other interface kept the old name. When can one expect this renaming to be consistent for all interfaces and where is it documented (you mention `enp4s6`, my interface got renamed `p18p1` - are those random digit or reflecting different types of interfaces (speed, medium, etc.)?)

Comment: No, they're the location on the bus.